# System crashes on boot if more than 2 drives in fstab?

Tags: boot, 18.04, fstab

So I'm setting up a new home server running Ubuntu 18.04. Everything goes smoothly, system works perfectly fine, until I try to install a 3rd drive.

Primary drive is a 250G SSD, secondary drive is a 1T WD Blue.

Those both work flawlessly.

Adding a third drive causes the system to boot into "emergency mode" every time. If I comment out the third drive in /etc/fstab, everything boots just fine.

My /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
UUID=ff5848e2-d97c-11e8-801c-70f39504462d / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID="d2fdaf92-a027-482a-a3b9-aa523c2a4ed2" /mnt/media ext4 defaults 0 0
#UUID="bceadd65-0e6b-4718-b1ce-c59fda688978" /mnt/media2 ext4 defaults 0 0
#/dev/dvd       /mnt/dvd        auto    user,noauto     0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

The drive for /mnt/media2 is another 1T WD Blue, tested and no errors found. The /dev/dvd is just a generic DVD drive, also in good working condition.

Any ideas on how to correct this? It's a pain having to log in and hand-mount these drives every time.

Comment: Have you checked your second drive for errors?  `fsck /dev/sdX#` that matches what your UUID is matched to for that `/mnt/media2` drive.  Usually maintenance mode is because it cannot access the drive properly and fails during the mount process of the boot.

Comment: fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sdc1: clean, 11/61054976 files, 4114691/244190390 blocks

Comment: Try it as `fsck -fy /dev/sdc1`.  Also, have you tried bypassing the `/mnt/media` but trying the `/mnt/media2`?

Comment: fsck -fy /dev/sdc1 comes back as clean. I can mount the drive just fine, so it's not that. /dev/dvd does the same thing. If I sudo mount them, it's fine. But mounting on boot fails every time and brings me to "maintenance mode."

Comment: Does the mount-point (`/mnt/media2`) exist?

Comment: Yes, same as /mnt/media and /mnt/dvd.

Comment: Is it external or internal?  If external, add `nofail` to the options part of the line just in case the drive is not quite ready when it goes to mount them.

Comment: Both are internal, both SATA.

Comment: This is definitely an odd one.  I personally have never bumped into an issue like this before.  I doubt I would be much more help.  The only other thing I could possibly think would be to try maybe creating the mount points in the `/media` folder and trying it that way.  You shouldn't need the one for the dvd since that should be an automount anyway.  Beyond that I don't know.  +1 for more visual to this question.  =)

Comment: Well, I just tried with the mount points in /media. Same result. As for the DVD, without a mount point it just errors out with "no mount point."

I'll solve it eventually. Lucky for me, that drive isn't needed yet.